# Stopping an infinite loop in a servlet from a jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, infinite-loop

I have a servlet which contains an infinite loop to receive data from a socket. There is an infinite loop because I want my application to continuously jump data to my socket until I stop it. I am hoping to pass the data to a jsp but it is not possible because of the infinite loop. Is there a way to stop the infinite loop with the click of a button in a jsp page? Included below are my codes. Sorry for the bad formatting.

Here is my DoPost in my Servlet.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

GazeDAO g = new GazeDAO();
String values, outStr, file, fileLocation;


try {
    String a = request.getParameter("action");



    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    PrintWriter wtr = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
    if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("Calibrate")) {
        wtr.println(g.calibrate());
        wtr.println(g.calibrateStart());
        wtr.flush();


    }

    if (a.equalsIgnoreCase("Record")) {
        wtr.println(g.enableSendData());
        wtr.println(g.sendData());
        wtr.println(g.blink());
        wtr.flush();
        BufferedReader bufRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        outStr = bufRead.readLine();

       while ((outStr = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
        values = g.output(outStr);
        data.add(values)

        }

        request.setAttribute("data", data);



        bufRead.close();

    }

    wtr.close();
    s.close();
    reader.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}


getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/hello.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

This is my jsp class

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
hello world!
<%
   ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) request.getAttribute("data");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the infinite lool

Comment: he is probably talking about the while loop. What you're looking to do is multi-thread.

Comment: Can you explain more on how I can use multi-thread to do this? @JonathanLaliberte

Comment: it basically means you have multiple pieces of code running same time. Worth doing a little research about

Comment: My problem is the infinite loop in the servlet. Since it is an infinite loop, it will never be forwarded to the jsp page where i can kill the thread. Is there a way around this? @JonathanLaliberte

Comment: What is `s` in your example, where you get the `InputStream` from?

Comment: Socket s = new Socket();
I am getting my inputstream from the socket. I send a command to the socket and it sends data back @NiklasP

Comment: So what is the code on the other side of the socket? Will the socket outputstream be closed so that you can end your while loop because you get `null` from the method `readLine()`?

Comment: The other end of the socket is a eye tracker device. The outputstream will never be null. The only way i can stop receiving data from outputstream is to terminate the application or terminate the eye tracker applicaiton @NiklasP

Comment: So if the `readLine()` method never will return null as you say, you need another rule to stop listening to the reader. As I don't know what you want to do and I don't know how to communicate to your eye tracker device, I cannot help you in detail.

Comment: I am communicating with my device over a socket port @NiklasP